# Getting an error while sending friend request

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I'm working on a Facebook clone and for the past few days I've been struggling with coming up with the logic to send friend requests.

Here is my FriendRequest Schema.

```
const friendRequestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sender: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  receiver: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["pending", "accepted", "rejected"],
    default: "pending",
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

Here is my send friend request button. The inputs are hidden so only the button shows up.

```
<form action="/friend-requests" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="sender" value="<%= id %>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="receiver" value="<%= user._id %>" />
  <button type="submit">Send Friend Request</button>
</form>
```

And here is my logic for sending a friend request.

```
// POST route to handle the friend request submission
router.post("/friend-requests", (req, res) => {
  const { sender, receiver } = req.body;

  // Create a new FriendRequest instance
  const newRequest = new FriendRequest({
    sender,
    receiver,
  });

  // Save the friend request to the database
  newRequest
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      // Redirect to a success page or send a response indicating success
      res.send("Friend request sent successfully!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle the error appropriately
      res.status(500).send("Error sending friend request");
    });
});
```

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to make it so when a user selects the `"Send Friend Request"` button on the users profile page, a request goes through and adds the user under the `pending` request. When said user checks their friend requests, it lists all pending requests and they can either accept or deny it. Pretty basic stuff but after combing through dozens and dozens of threads over the past few days I'm having trouble getting it all set up.

**UPDATE - MORE CODE**

Here is my GET for the `user` profile page. It lists all your own status updates on your page.

```
router.get("/:user", function (req, res, next) {
  Status.find({}, "content author createdAt")
    .sort({ title: 1 })
    .exec(function (err, list_status) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.render("profile", {
        status_list: list_status,
        id: id,
      });
    });
});
```

This code posts a status update from the `index` page via a form.

```
router.post("/:user", [
  // Validate and sanitize fields.
  body("content", "Content must not be empty.")
    .trim()
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .escape(),
  // Process request after validation and sanitization.
  (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    const status = new Status({
      content: req.body.content,
      author: req.body.author,
    });

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      async.parallel((err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        res.render("profile", {
          content: content,
          author: author,
          status,
          errors: errors.array(),
        });
      });
      return;
    }
    status.save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.redirect("/");
    });
  },
]);
```

My User schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, "can't be blank"],
    match: [/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, "is invalid"],
    index: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, "can't be blank"],
    match: [/\S+@\S+\.\S+/, "is invalid"],
    index: true,
  },
  password: String,
  email: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  friends: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  ],
});
```

Comment: Please be more specific regarding the errors you're seeing or unexpected behaviours when posting questions.
What happens if you `console.log` the values of `sender` and `receiver`? Are you using express body-parser middleware to parse the form contents?

Comment: @BrunoFarias ah that seems to be my problem then. Sender is showing my id `6454407483df47caef5004e2` properly but receiver is showing blank. And yes I am using `express body-parser`. `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`

Comment: Then `user` or `user._id` is empty or null in your form. Can you add all the related code?

Comment: @SuleymanSah just updated my code now. Working on that now. Trying to find a way to sort through the User schema to get the `id` of whoevers page I'm on.